# How to Change the Radio Button Position in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have implemented Radio button using custom rendering in Xamarin. The radio button is aligned left and text is aligned right by default. How can we change the position of radio button to the right?

Xaml Code is below

```
 <StackLayout   HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <control:BindableRadioGroup   x:Name="SortPicker"
                                          TextColor="Gray"  
                                          CheckedChanged="OnCheckedChanged"
                                          Padding="50,0,0,10"
                                          WidthRequest="1100"
                                          Spacing="20">

            </control:BindableRadioGroup>
          </StackLayout>
```

Render Code:

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomRadioButton> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var radButton = new RadioButton(Context);
                colorStateList = radButton.TextColors; 
                radButton.CheckedChange += this.RadButtonCheckedChange;

                SetNativeControl(radButton);
            }

            Control?.SetPadding(30, Control.PaddingTop, 0, Control.PaddingBottom);
            Control.Text = e.NewElement.Text;
            Control.Checked = e.NewElement.Checked;
            UpdateTextColor();

            if (e.NewElement.FontSize > 0)
            {
                Control.TextSize = (float)e.NewElement.FontSize;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewElement.FontName))
            {
                Control.Typeface = TrySetFont(e.NewElement.FontName);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you show us the XAML code / renderer code

Comment: @Jorydy: I have added my code sample

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling supportsRtl property to true in your application manifest:

```
<application android:label="app label" android:supportsRtl="true"/>
```

and setting the Control's LayoutDirectionProperty like so:

```
Control.LayoutDirection = LayoutDirection.Rtl;
```